# add html in wordpress label

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress

I need to customize some menu items voices (not all) in wordpress.

Is it possible to enable html/css in the title label?

This is my situation:

[image]

I need that only ON results blu.

[image]

I've tried to put html in this label but html doesn't run in that label.
Someone know if is possible enabled html in that label, maybe with PHP?

Thx so much!

**EDIT: 
Tnx so much the function run!
There is a problem...
I dont need that feature for all the menu's voices, because some voices have only a word.
You know how i can resolve?
:)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To do this to ALL titles, you can add the following function to your functions.php file:

```
add_filter('the_title', function($title){

    $parts = explode(' ', $title);
    $parts[0] = '<span style="color:#42343;">'.$parts[0].'</span>';
    return implode(' ', $parts);
});
```

It would be better to add a class rather than a style so you can target specific titles in different ways, eg:

```
$parts[0] = '<span class="firstword">'.$parts[0].'</span>';

/*your style.css file*/
.home h2.title span.firstword {color: #333333;}
.about h2.title span.firstword {color: #42343;}
```

EDIT as per your comment, this is how you can limit it to only effect titles with more than one word:

```
add_filter('the_title', function($title){

    $parts = explode(' ', $title);
    //if there are more than 1 word
    if(count($parts)>1){
        $parts[0] = '<span style="color:#42343;">'.$parts[0].'</span>';
    }
    return implode(' ', $parts);
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Adding html to your title is not really recommended. It is possible through several ways, but it will mess up with the title, as it will make the html displaying on it which doesn't look good.

If you still find the need to display html on title, i can work it out for you. Leave me a comment and I'll see what I can get